# Double Jump Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new to developing games with Phaser3. I am going crazy, for days I have been looking for a way to do a 'double jump'. and I can't ...
I found many questions similar to this one here, but none gave me a concrete solution ...

I would like the player to double jump if I double-click the 'up' cursor.

I'm at this point:

```
function update() {


    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-130);
        player.anims.play('left', true);

    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(130);
        player.anims.play('right', true);

    } else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.play('idle', true);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
        salto();
    } 

}
```

Comment: the function 'salto()' is: 
`
function salto(){
    player.setVelocityY('100');
 }
`

Comment: Salto means jump in english?

Comment: @JohnBubriski ... yes

Answer (score 1):

It might look something like this:

```
function update() {
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-130);
        player.anims.play('left', true);

    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(130);
        player.anims.play('right', true);

    } else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.play('idle', true);
    }

    if (player.body.touching.down) {
        player.jumpCount = 0;
    }

    var canDoubleJump = player.jumpCount < 2;

    if (cursors.up.isDown && (player.body.touching.down || canDoubleJump ) {
        player.jumpCount++;
        salto();
    }
}
```

Track the current `jumpCount` which you increment when the player jumps, and then reset it to 0 when they are touching the ground.  They can only jump if they're touching the ground OR they haven't jumped twice already.

I assumed that you can add `jumpCount` to the player object.

Comment: Now when I press the up cursor the second time, the player quickly falls to the ground and repeats the jump action.
How can I change it so that if I press once the player jumps a certain height and if I press the second time it jumps another height?

Comment: You may need to include your `salto()` code. You can edit your original question to include it, instead of adding a comment.